# Reading XML with ReadSubTree() fails in custom MessageInspector

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

I'm writing a custom MessageInspector in order to be able to validate incoming XML documents according to an XSD. (This happens before message de-serialization.)

I get an exception

> "ReadSubtree() can be called only if the reader is on an element
>   node."

on the call to ReadSubTree() on this line:

```
XmlReader bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadSubtree();
```

Here is the code for the method (copied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx)

```
private void ValidateMessageBody(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, bool isRequest)
    {
        if (!message.IsFault)
        {
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            XmlReader bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadSubtree();
            XmlReaderSettings wrapperSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            wrapperSettings.CloseInput = true;
            wrapperSettings.Schemas = schemaSet;
            wrapperSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None;
            wrapperSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            wrapperSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(InspectionValidationHandler);
            XmlReader wrappedReader = XmlReader.Create(bodyReader, wrapperSettings);

            // pull body into a memory backed writer to validate
            this.isRequest = isRequest;
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDictionaryWriter xdw = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(memStream);
            xdw.WriteNode(wrappedReader, false);
            xdw.Flush(); 
            memStream.Position = 0;
            XmlDictionaryReader xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(memStream, quotas);

            // reconstruct the message with the validated body
            Message replacedMessage = Message.CreateMessage(message.Version, null, xdr);
            replacedMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(message.Headers);
            replacedMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(message.Properties);
            message = replacedMessage;
        }
    }
```

I'm using Fiddler to send a POST request to my WCF service (IIS hosted). The content-type is set to application/xml.

My input XML looks like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns="myNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="0.52">
<Sender id="1" email="..." />
    ...
    ...
```

So, what could be the problem? The docs didn't help me understanding what is wrong. I'm thinking the problem is actually with the GetReaderAtBodyContents() call.

Comment: What's the value of `message.GetReaderAtBodyContents().NodeType`?

Comment: The value is element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the node is an empty node, judging by the self-closing tag.

ReadSubTree might throw an exception because of this...

In your case you would just need to iterate over the attributes, based on the node name...